# How to process a list of complex data structures

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, highcharts, mapreduce

In High Charts i have an array as follows,
But if i try to set extremes of the chart by returning the Highest value of the Array, its showing NaN Error.

```
function aoDashboardData() {
var data = [

     {      type: "",
            data: [{
                x: 0.0,
                low: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 15),
                high: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 10),
                color: "#4B0081"
            },
            {
                x: 0.0,
                low: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 15),
                high: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 15),
                color: "#00BFFE"
            },
            {
                x: 0.0,
                low: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 20),
                high: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 0),
                color: "#0047AB"
            },
            {
                x: 0.0,
                low: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                high: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                color: "#4682B4"
            },
            {
                x: 0.0,
                low: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 20),
                high: Date.UTC(2016, 12, 31),
                color: "#008081"
            }]
        },
        {
            type: 'line',
            data: [
                {
                    x: 0.0,
                    y: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 15),
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/monitor.png)',
                    }
                },
                {
                    x: 0.0,
                    y: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 10),
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/optimise.png)',
                    }
                },
                {
                    x: 0.0,
                    y: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 15),
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/pilot.png)',
                    }
                },
                {
                    x: 0.0,
                    y: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/model.png)',
                    }
                },
                {
                    x: 0.0,
                    y: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/deploy.png)',
                    }
                }

            ]
        },



        {
            type: "",
            data: [{
                x: 1.0,
                low: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 15),
                high: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 10),
                color: "#4B0081"
            },
            {
                x: 1.0,
                low: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 15),
                high: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 15),
                color: "#00BFFE"
            },
            {
                x: 1.0,
                low: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 20),
                high: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 0),
                color: "#0047AB"
            },
            {
                x: 1.0,
                low: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                high: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                color: "#4682B4"
            },
            {
                x: 1.0,
                low: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 20),
                high: Date.UTC(2016, 12, 31),
                color: "#008081"
            }]
        },
        {
            type: 'line',
            data: [
                {
                    x: 1.0,
                    y: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 15),
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/monitor.png)',
                    }
                },
                {
                    x: 1.0,
                    y: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 10),
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/optimise.png)',
                    }
                },
                {
                    x: 1.0,
                    y: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 15),
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/pilot.png)',
                    }
                },
                {
                    x: 1.0,
                    y: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/model.png)',
                    }
                },
                {
                    x: 1.0,
                    y: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/deploy.png)',
                    }
                }

            ]
        },

         {
             type: "",
             data: [{
                 x: 2.0,
                 low: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 15),
                 high: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 10),
                 color: "#4B0081"
             },
             {
                 x: 2.0,
                 low: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 15),
                 high: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 15),
                 color: "#00BFFE"
             },
             {
                 x: 2.0,
                 low: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 20),
                 high: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 0),
                 color: "#0047AB"
             },
             {
                 x: 2.0,
                 low: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                 high: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                 color: "#4682B4"
             },
             {
                 x: 2.0,
                 low: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 20),
                 high: Date.UTC(2016, 12, 31),
                 color: "#008081"
             }]
         },
         {
             type: 'line',
             data: [
                 {
                     x: 2.0,
                     y: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 15),
                     marker: {
                         symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/monitor.png)',
                     }
                 },
                 {
                     x: 2.0,
                     y: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 10),
                     marker: {
                         symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/optimise.png)',
                     }
                 },
                 {
                     x: 2.0,
                     y: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 15),
                     marker: {
                         symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/pilot.png)',
                     }
                 },
                 {
                     x: 2.0,
                     y: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                     marker: {
                         symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/model.png)',
                     }
                 },
                 {
                     x: 2.0,
                     y: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                     marker: {
                         symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/deploy.png)',
                     }
                 }

             ]
         },


          {
              type: "",
              data: [{
                  x: 3.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 15),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 10),
                  color: "#4B0081"
              },
              {
                  x: 3.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 15),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 15),
                  color: "#00BFFE"
              },
              {
                  x: 3.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 20),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 0),
                  color: "#0047AB"
              },
              {
                  x: 3.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                  color: "#4682B4"
              },
              {
                  x: 3.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 20),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 12, 31),
                  color: "#008081"
              }]
          },
          {
              type: 'line',
              data: [
                  {
                      x: 3.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 15),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/monitor.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 3.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 10),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/optimise.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 3.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 15),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/pilot.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 3.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/model.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 3.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/deploy.png)',
                      }
                  }

              ]
          },

          {
              type: "",
              data: [{
                  x: 4.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 15),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 10),
                  color: "#4B0081"
              },
              {
                  x: 4.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 15),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 15),
                  color: "#00BFFE"
              },
              {
                  x: 4.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 20),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 0),
                  color: "#0047AB"
              },
              {
                  x: 1.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                  color: "#4682B4"
              },
              {
                  x: 4.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 20),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 12, 31),
                  color: "#008081"
              }]
          },
          {
              type: 'line',
              data: [
                  {
                      x: 4.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 15),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/monitor.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 4.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 10),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/optimise.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 4.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 15),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/pilot.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 4.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/model.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 4.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/deploy.png)',
                      }
                  }

              ]
          }

          ,

          {
              type: "",
              data: [{
                  x: 5.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 15),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 10),
                  color: "#4B0081"
              },
              {
                  x: 5.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 15),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 15),
                  color: "#00BFFE"
              },
              {
                  x: 5.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 20),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 0),
                  color: "#0047AB"
              },
              {
                  x: 5.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                  color: "#4682B4"
              },
              {
                  x: 5.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 20),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 12, 31),
                  color: "#008081"
              }]
          },
          {
              type: 'line',
              data: [
                  {
                      x: 5.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 15),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/monitor.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 5.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 10),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/optimise.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 5.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 15),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/pilot.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 5.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/model.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 5.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/deploy.png)',
                      }
                  }

              ]
          }
          ,

          {
              type: "",
              data: [{
                  x: 6.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 15),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 10),
                  color: "#4B0081"
              },
              {
                  x: 6.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 15),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 15),
                  color: "#00BFFE"
              },
              {
                  x: 6.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 20),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 0),
                  color: "#0047AB"
              },
              {
                  x: 6.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                  color: "#4682B4"
              },
              {
                  x: 6.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 20),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 12, 31),
                  color: "#008081"
              }]
          },
          {
              type: 'line',
              data: [
                  {
                      x: 6.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 15),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/monitor.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 6.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 10),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/optimise.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 6.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 15),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/pilot.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 6.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/model.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 6.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/deploy.png)',
                      }
                  }

              ]
          }
          ,

          {
              type: "",
              data: [{
                  x: 7.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 15),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 10),
                  color: "#4B0081"
              },
              {
                  x: 7.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 15),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 15),
                  color: "#00BFFE"
              },
              {
                  x: 7.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 20),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 0),
                  color: "#0047AB"
              },
              {
                  x: 1.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                  color: "#4682B4"
              },
              {
                  x: 7.0,
                  low: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 20),
                  high: Date.UTC(2016, 12, 31),
                  color: "#008081"
              }]
          },
          {
              type: 'line',
              data: [
                  {
                      x: 7.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 15),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/monitor.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 7.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 10),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/optimise.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 7.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 15),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/pilot.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 7.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/model.png)',
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      x: 7.0,
                      y: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                      marker: {
                          symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/deploy.png)',
                      }
                  }

              ]
          }
]

return data;
```

}

The code i tried to get the maximum value is  :

```
MinAssortmentValue = Math.min.apply(Math, chartlength);
```

Here is the updated jsFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/sarav4gs/jbmk9tb1/3/

Can Anyone help me to fix it? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: where do you get `chartlength` from?

Comment: what do you mean by array's maximum value it is a bit vague can you explain a bit more?highest value?or last element in array?

Comment: @guradio sorry abt tht, i mean Highest value

Comment: @NinaScholz you can refer this fiddle for full code : http://jsfiddle.net/sarav4gs/L4fx5mbd/4/

Comment: @DownVoter please let me know whats wrong in my question?

Comment: i see no `Math.min` in the code of jsfiddle. please update your question with the missing pieces.

Comment: now you can check the given jsfiddle @NinaScholz

Comment: @IamSarav - what are you going to achieve with `Math.min.apply(Math, 16)`? (your fiddles `chartlength` has assigned 16) - `Math.min` awaits some values, in order to compare them and returning the one that turns out to have the lower value. Now with using `apply` you need to pass kind of a (arguments) list to it. Thus delegating, as in your case, a number to `Math.min` does result in the attempt making an array from a number value which does not work - the result for e.g. `Math.min.apply(Math, [])` equals `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` ...

Comment: @IamSarav ...  On the other hand passing 16 directly to `Math.min` does not make any sense either. Being the only argument does make it also the result of this operation. Though - what should be the argument you really want to pass via `Math.min.apply`?

Comment: @PeterSeliger you are right. so chart.series.length will return the value - 16. and it cant be compared by the 'Math' method. but i am trying to pass 'chart.series' which is a full array and i want to find out the highest/lowest value or the Index of the array and set that value in highchart 'setExtremes' method to change my charts values. suppose if i have 50 objects in my array, i have to show only 5 items on load, and when clicked pagination controls, accordingly i have to iterate the next set of series objects. this is what i am trying to do

Comment: @IamSarav - I already did assume this. Then, depending on your use case you either need to write your own `Array.sort` comparator function depending on the exact value of a `chart.series`-item that you are going to compare - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort, or even going for the probably more suitable `Array.reduce` approach - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... referring to this comment of mine - [How to process a list of complex data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367981/how-to-retrieve-arrays-highest-value-getting-nan-error#comment64155852_38367981) - the sketched approach might look like that, even though I still do not really know what are the object properties of a chart item you are going to compare and/or extract ...

```
var
    chart = $('#ao-projectssummry-chart').highcharts(),

    minMaxValues = chart.series.reduce(function (collector, item, idx/*, list*/) {
        var
            dataMin  = item.dataMin,
            dataMax  = item.dataMax,
            minValue = Math.min(collector.minValue, dataMin),
            maxValue = Math.max(collector.maxValue, dataMax);

        if (minValue == dataMin) {
            collector.minValue = dataMin;
            collector.minValueItemIndex = idx;
        }
        if (maxValue == dataMax) {
            collector.maxValue = dataMax;
            collector.maxValueItemIndex = idx;
        }
        return collector;

    }, {
        minValue: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
        maxValue: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
        minValueItemIndex: -1,
        maxValueItemIndex: -1
    }),

    minAssortmentValue = minMaxValues.minValue,
    maxAssortmentValue = minMaxValues.maxValue;

console.log("minMaxValues : ", minMaxValues);
console.log("minAssortmentValue, maxAssortmentValue : ", minAssortmentValue, maxAssortmentValue);
```

Pasting the just provided code snipped into the console of your provided fiddle does cause the following output:

```
minMaxValues :  Object {
    minValue: 1458000000000,
    maxValue: 1485820800000,
    minValueItemIndex: 9,
    maxValueItemIndex: 14
}
minAssortmentValue, maxAssortmentValue :  1458000000000 1485820800000
```

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your time and this great help!!! let me try this snippet in my code and see if i can achieve my scenario :)